# Can I overcome ElGamal malleability with AES preprocessing?

Tags: aes, elgamal-encryption, chosen-ciphertext-attack, malleability, hybrid-encryption

So textbook ElGamal is known to be vulnerable to CPA, and although there are several proposals (DHAES/EIES) for modifications none of those are formally accepted or standardized.

My question is whether if I simply "preprocess" the plaintext with the good-old hybrid asymmetric method won't that solve the chiphertext modification problem? (yes I know a DoS-like error is still present if the AES key is altered midway)

Comment: Textbook ElGamal is _not_ vulnerable to CPA. It is vulnerable to CCA(2) attacks.

Comment: Can you quickly line out (using pseudo-code or $\LaTeX$) what precisely you mean with "pre-processing" or are you asking for a more general "secure authenticated encryption of the plaintext"?

Comment: Why would you use ElGamal over IES style algorithms if you don't need the homomorphic properties of ElGamal?